# Is there a way to access NFS (v3 or v4) shares using Java?

Tags: java, nio, java-7, nfs, multiplatform

we're working on a project where we need access to some NFS shares. Our clients use Windows, Linux and OS X, though we don't want to mount those shares, but instead simply access it for example via `nfs://192.168.0.1/path/file.txt`.

I searched the web and came across WebNFS, YaNFS, XFile, jFTP, and some others. But none of them seems to be under active development. Or have I just accessed the wrong web sites? I also came across NIO, but couldn't find any useful information about it...

Our server administrator told me, that for him it would be the easiest to use NFSv4 because of user rights handling, but if necessary NFSv3 would also do the job.

So what the best way to access NFS shares using Java 7?

Comment: This is a Java NFS client library:  http://avdhome.tripod.com/rfsclient_Copy_1.html

Comment: Whoa.... hosted on tripod, copyright 1998.... would be surprised if that guy was up to date, but it might be worth a look. I was poking around for the same thing recently and I concluded that NFS simply doesn't warrant developer interest any more. We ended up using WebDAV. Good luck !